# How to navigate to section in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to navigate to a specific section on the page with React Router, but instead landing on the top of the page. Manually entering the url does send me to the right spot. What am i doing wrong?

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Link to="/navbar#section2">Go to section 2</Link>
        <Link to="/navbar#section1">Go to section 1</Link>
        <Sidebar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/navbar" exact component={Navbar} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired functionality using normal `<a>` tags instead of `Link` component

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <a href="#section2">Go to section 2</a>
        <a href="#section1">Go to section 1</a>
        <Sidebar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/navbar" exact component={Navbar} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```